# Increase paddingTop of div element when input text field is pressed, reduce it otherwise

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `input` text field inside a `div` element in my HTML. I want to increase the `padding-top` of the `div` when the input text field is clicked, reduce it otherwise.

- My **HTML**:

  ```
        <div id="quarter_tenure">
            <p id="date"><b>Occupancy Date</b> :<br>
                   <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datefilter" value="" onclick="reset_size()"/></p>
        </div>
  ```
- My **Javascript**:

  ```
  function reset_size(){
      let x = document.getElementById("quarter_tenure");

      if(document.getElementById("datepicker") === document.activeElement){
          x.style.paddingTop="30em";
      } 
      else{
          x.style.paddingTop="15em";
      }
  }
  ```

But when I execute the code, the `padding-top` doesn't change, regardless of me clicking the `input` text field. What is wrong here? How do I fix it?

---

**EDIT:** As @Timothy Alexis Vass had suggested, I've added his code into my `css`:

```
#quarter_tenure{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border:dotted;
    margin-top: 8em ;
    padding-top: 15em;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(228, 255, 254);
    transition: 2s;
}

#quarter_tenure:focus-within {
    padding-top: 30em;
}
```

But it's still not working.

Comment: how are you listening to the action? Or how do you trigger this function?

Comment: with the help of `onclick()`

Comment: Oh I see now, I think it's better practice and less buggy overall to use event listeners with stuff like focused attribute, maybe give it a try and see if adding a event listener to trigger your function would work instead of the onclick() in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two events `onfocus` and `onfocusout`:

```js
function goUpSize() {
   document.getElementById("quarter_tenure").style.paddingTop = "6em";
}

function goDownSize() {
   document.getElementById("quarter_tenure").style.paddingTop = "1em";
}
```

```html
 <div id="quarter_tenure">
        <p id="date">
            <b>Occupancy Date</b> :<br>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datefilter" value="" onfocus="goUpSize()" onfocusout="goDownSize()" />
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with css only.

```css
#quarter_tenure {
  padding-top: 1em;
  transition: 1s;
}

#quarter_tenure:focus-within {
  padding-top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="quarter_tenure">
  <p id="date">
    <b>Occupancy Date</b> :<br>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datefilter" value="" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried it, doesn't work. Please have a look in my code, I've updated my `css`

Comment: Look at the code I added, it is only html and css, without any JavaScript... Click "Run code snippet" and you will see that it works.

Comment: I mean, that when I integrate your code into my css it's not working.

Comment: So you have to remove your JavaScript code and do it with only html and css! :D Look at the code and do it like that, it is very simple.

Comment: Yes bro, I've tested it only after removing my javascript code.

Comment: @user15089140 If you have used the code exactly like I have provided, you will get the proper result. Click "Run code snippet" and you will see how it works.